# Getting fetch error when deploying Nextjs / TS app to Vercel

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, vercel, sanity

Im getting this error when I try to deploy an app using Nextjs / TS / Sanity to Vercel

```
18:39:44.458] Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
[18:39:44.458] TypeError: fetch failed
[18:39:44.458]     at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:14062:11)
[18:39:44.459]     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
[18:39:44.459]     at async fetchPageInfo (/vercel/path0/.next/server/pages/index.js:1176:17)
[18:39:44.459]     at async getStaticProps (/vercel/path0/.next/server/pages/index.js:1037:22)
[18:39:44.460]     at async renderToHTML (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:389:20)
[18:39:44.460]     at async /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/export/worker.js:354:36
[18:39:44.460]     at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:79:20)
[18:39:44.461] info  - Generating static pages (3/3)
[18:39:44.464] 
[18:39:44.464] > Build error occurred
[18:39:44.465] Error: Export encountered errors on following paths:
[18:39:44.466]  /
[18:39:44.466]     at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/export/index.js:425:19
[18:39:44.466]     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
[18:39:44.466]     at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:79:20)
[18:39:44.466]     at async /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:1422:21
[18:39:44.467]     at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:79:20)
[18:39:44.467]     at async /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:1280:17
[18:39:44.467]     at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:79:20)
[18:39:44.467]     at async Object.build [as default] (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:73:29)
[18:39:44.517] Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

The error comes from this:

```
export const  fetchPageInfo   = async () => {
    const res = await fetch (`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL}/api/getPageInfo`)

    process

    const data = await res.json()

    const pageInfo: PageInfo = data.pageInfo
    
    //console.log(pageInfo)

    return pageInfo

}
```

When I run it locally there is no issue, the value of this variable NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL is https://localhost:3000 so I thought, of course it won't work during the building process, it's trying to fetch info from that url.

So with a very basic trial and error I deploy the app w/o all the queries and the components which use that data and it worked, even tried the endpoints of the API and they also worked. So then I updated the app adding all the queries and the components again but with value of NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL being the url of the deploy app, even I tryed to deploy another instance of the up but I keep getting the same error.